# Double Port forwarding

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a Telkom 105W router that my ADSL is setup in.
Then I have a SCM router that is plugged into the Telkom router and I connect to it wirelessly for my internet (my Telkom router's antenna is broken...)

```
Telkom IP is 10.0.0.2
SMC is 192.168.2.1
```

How do I forward ports to the SMC from the telkom one, so I can access the SMC router via a different por? I know I can just go to `192.168.2.1` but I want to use a dynDNS client so I can access the SMC router as well.

Comment: It isn't the right place for this question (as it has nothing to do with programing). Hopefully it will be bounced to the appropriate SE site.

Comment: oops, So what is the right site then?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a good reason to be doing double NAT?  If not, then leave NAT enabled on the Telkom ADSL gateway, and turn it off for your SMC.

Basically for most home networks you have the broadband gateway (the cable or DSL gateway) do NAT and DHCP for the whole network, and make sure nothing else on the network is doing NAT or DHCP. If your broadband modem is just a plain modem and not a gateway (it can't do NAT and DHCP), then connect your own gateway directly to the modem and you have that device do NAT and DHCP, and make sure nothing else is doing NAT and DHCP.

Some gateways let you disable NAT and DHCP. They may call this "bridge mode". Some gateways don't let you disable those services very easily, so you have to disable DHCP (or set the size of the DHCP address pool to zero), and then stop using the WAN port -- just plug a LAN port into the upstream gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample map:

> public Ip:port xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
>   Telkom WAN -> Telkom LAN 10.0.0.2 ->
>   SCM WAN 10.0.0.x:80 -> SCM LAN
>   192.168.2.1 -> Machine LAN 192.168.2.x:80

You basically have a WAN IP and port on each router that has to be forwarded to the corresponding IP and port on the device on the LAN past it.